Is Salah nullified if I pray facing a door and someone opens it?
Salamu walaikum,
I usually pray in my room and the qibla is facing my door, so I usually pray with the door in front of me closed, so that I can focus. iF one opens the door, not knowing, that I was praying, does this nullify my prayer (or break it), because he interrupted me.
Jazakallah Khairan.

Lock the door. Install a lock on it if it does not have a lock. Maybe put a sign on the other side of the door to let people know you are praying.
According to the majority of the schools of thought (Hanafi, Shafi'i, Maliki - the stance of the  Hanbalis is the same as long as it is not a black dog), prayer is not nullified by anyone passing in front of you.

‏ لا يقطع الصلاة شىء وادرءوا ما استطعتم فإنما هو شيطان
Nothing interrupts prayer, but repulse as much as you can anyone who passes in front of you, for he is just a devil.
— Abu Dawud corroborated by  Bukhari, Muwatta Malik etc.

And the ahadith which mention some things are understood to mean that they disrupt concentration, not that they nullify the prayer.
